# How to show multiple data in one plot in python?

Tags: python, data-science, data-mining

I am using a binary classification dataset. I want a plan that shows the first column showing the age of the people, the next column showing the age of the first graders, and the third column showing the age of the second graders. Please advise what I should do

```
age | class
------------
 1 |  1
 2 |  1
 3 |  0
 4 |  1
 5 |  0
 6 |  1
 7 |  1
 8 |  0
 9 |  0
10 |  1



import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


df = pd.read_csv (r'test.csv')

firstClassDf = df[df['class'] == '0']
print(firstClassDf.shape)

print(firstClassDf.head())


secondClassDf = df[df['class'] == '1']
print(secondClassDf.shape)

boxplot1 = df.boxplot(column='age')
plt.figure()

boxplot2 = firstClassDf.boxplot(column='age')
plt.figure()

boxplot3 = secondClassDf.boxplot(column='age')
plt.figure()

print(plt.show())
```

**Expected Plot**
[image]

Comment: Could you show a preview of test.csv? df.head() would be sufficient

Comment: @DSteman Yes, of course

Comment: And what does your desired output look like?

Comment: @DSteman I've added the expected design

Comment: My data view is something like the one I wrote above, one column for people and the second column for the class. @paradocslover

Comment: So you're trying plot the mean age for all samples, samples where class == 1 and samples where class == 0?

Comment: @DSteman Yes, exactly

Comment: That was not entirely clear from the question. Always try to include all the details in your question so it becomes easier for people to help you :)

Comment: @DSteman Thank you. Now if I want to do this for all the data, what should I do because I delete the mean command, an error occurs

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The code should yield the expected plot. What is on the y-axis and x-axis of your expected plot?

Comment: Axis y: The exact age of each person, not their average age @DSteman

Comment: Then you have to change the expected plot in your question because that is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments I understand you're looking for something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [['age', 'class'],
 [1,1],
 [2,1],
 [3,0],
 [4,1],
 [5,0],
 [6,1],
 [7,1],
 [8,0],
 [9,0],
[10,1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data[1:])
df.columns = data[0]

bar1 = df['age'].mean()
bar2 = df[df['class'] == 0]['age'].mean()
bar3 = df[df['class'] == 1]['age'].mean()
labels = ['all', 'class1', 'class2']

print (plt.bar(labels, [bar1,bar2,bar3]))
```